# WebApi Pagination not working, page is always 0 even when I set url parameter correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

The api controller method is this:

```
        public IHttpActionResult GettblEmpleados(int page, int pageSize)
        {
            var query = db.SPEmpleadosIntranet().ToList();

            var totalCount = query.Count();
            var totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)totalCount / pageSize);

            var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(Request);
            var prevLink = page > 0 ? urlHelper.Link("Empleados", new { page = page - 1, pageSize = pageSize }) : "";
            var nextLink = page < totalPages - 1 ? urlHelper.Link("Empleados", new { page = page + 1, pageSize = pageSize }) : "";

            var results = query
            .Skip(pageSize * page)
            .Take(pageSize)
            .ToList();

            return Ok(query);
        }
```

And the url I use to consume the service is:

However, page is always 0, then prevLink is always empty
http://localhost:12929/api/Empleados?page=0&pageSize=10

The error I get is this: (sorry framework its in spanish)

Translatio says it cant find the path /Empleados

> No se encuentra ninguna ruta con el nombre 'Empleados' en la colección de rutas.\r\nNombre del parámetro: name"

this is the controller

```
public class EmpleadosController : ApiController
{
```

and this is the globa.asax

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Clear();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
```

Update1

this is webapiconfig

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) 
        { 
            // Web API configuration and services 
            // Web API routes 
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(); 
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( 
                name: "DefaultApi", 
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}", 
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional } 
            ); 
        }
```

Comment: Whats the name of your Controller? Also what is your route configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();` you can use [Route Prefixes](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#prefixes) as follows and because you are using the [UrlHelper.Link Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.routing.urlhelper.link%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) you need to set the [Route Name](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#route-names)

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Empleados")]   
public class EmpleadosController : ApiController {

    [Route("", Name="Empleados")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GettblEmpleados(int page, int pageSize) {
        var query = db.SPEmpleadosIntranet().ToList();

        var totalCount = query.Count();
        var totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)totalCount / pageSize);

        var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(Request);
        var prevLink = page > 0 ? urlHelper.Link("Empleados", new { page = page - 1, pageSize = pageSize }) : "";
        var nextLink = page < totalPages - 1 ? urlHelper.Link("Empleados", new { page = page + 1, pageSize = pageSize }) : "";

        var results = query
        .Skip(pageSize * page)
        .Take(pageSize)
        .ToList();

        return Ok(query);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your current URL you aren't referring to your action...

Controller / Action / Params

in your webapiconfig -->

```
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}"
```

http://localhost:12929/api/Empleados/GettblEmpleados?page=0&pageSize=10

Comment: Share your route configuration

Comment: I pasted above the global.asax

Comment: I have to say this is an asp.net mvc application where I am hosting the api controllers, then I guess I am missing something on global.asax

Comment: Check out this informative page on routing for WebApi --> http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: please see webapiconfig

Comment: ah...your template needs {action} between {controller} and {id}

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell the method which Http method it matches to. Try decorating it with the following attribute:

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult GettblEmpleados(int page, int pageSize)
{
```